# JFileChooser on OS X

Tags: java, macos, widget, jfilechooser

JFileChooser looks nothing like the native widget. I seem to remember reading some hack to get it look like the native widget but searching for it know i can't seem to find it again i came across posts that suggest using java.awt.FileChooser but that class does not seem to be in the distribution. How can i make JFileChooser make look like the native widget?

Answer (score 5):

`java.awt.FileDialog` will be the classes the posts meant. It is, unsurprisingly, more limited that the Swing version. All Java SE implementations are required to have the `FileDialog` class (although headless configurations may not be able to do anything useful with it).

Comment: "more limited" sure -- except in how the native file choosers are all infinitely superior to JFileChooser....

Comment: Superior in looks, perhaps, but missing basic features like being able to choose which format to save in make it kind of pointless overall. :(

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [this page](http://nadeausoftware.com/node/89#UsingtheJFileChoosertogetMacfileandfoldericons). It goes through a lot of UI tweaks, but the third one is most relevant: "Using the JFileChooser to get Mac file and folder icons."

Answer (score 4):

It may be worth a look at [the Quaqua look and feel](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/), it replaces the file chooser with a much better and more native version, including folder colouring etc.