# Using a FileDialog to choose a file of a certain extension

Tags: java, filedialog, filechooser

I am trying to use a FileDialog file chooser because I really need java app to have the native apple file chooser (I know we all hate hate the lack of portability but this is what I need).  I am trying to make my file chooser allow the user to pick files that end with .ws.  Here is what I tried:

```
            FileDialog fd = new         

           FileDialog(_sharedInstance,rsc.str("480"),FileDialog.LOAD);
           // fd.setFile("*.ws");
            class WSFilter implements FilenameFilter {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return (name.endsWith(".ws"));
                }
            };
            FilenameFilter wsFilter = new WSFilter();

            fd.setFilenameFilter(wsFilter);
            fd.setDirectory(_projectsBaseDir.getPath());
            fd.setLocation(50,50);

           // fd.setFile("*");
            fd.setVisible(true);
```

For some reason my file chooser won't allow me to pick any files.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer was I need this call: System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "false");

Comment: Is there any relevant documentation you can link to?

Comment: Not really.  In the following thread someone explained to me how that you need to set that global property in order to allow FileDialog to accept diectories, I had just forgotten to set it back.  This is one of the many reasons people will tell you not to use FileDialog.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224714/how-can-i-make-a-java-filedialog-accept-directories-as-its-filetype-in-os-x

Answer (score 1):

Why not use JFileChooser?

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(new File(filename));
fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(new MyFilter());

class MyFilter extends javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        String filename = file.getName();
        return filename.endsWith(".java");
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return "*.java";
    }
}
```

Comment: Because I need to use the mac native file chooser and JFileChooser does not allow this.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't this been asked before?

Anyway, you may try to change L&F and keep using JFileChooser.

I've heard this one is good:

[Quaqua Look and Feel](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/)

[image]

Comment: We are currently using quaqua but many mac users feel that it is not an adequate interpretation of the Mac GUI so I have been tasked to implement the file choosers to use the native file chooser.

Comment: mmhh I see, depending on how relevant this is you may either implement your own subclass and add the missing parts  ( which I think it would be quite hard ) or you may create a small native application which returns the filepath when invoked. That shouldn't be too hard to do ( when you know Objective-C :P  ) T