# In a OS portable fasion, how could I retrieve a Directory Path with a FileDialog using AWT?

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I'm beginning to dabble with GUI frameworks and have hit a wall in the development of a data-managing GUI I'm creating for my father, using AWT.

I want to select a directory using **FileDialog**, in order to retrieve its PATH but for now I can only select files

There aren't concrete restrictions but for my sake:

- It only uses AWT framework, no Swing
- It's OS portable
- It specifically selects directories, NOT files

I've searched for about 1.5 hours with mostly fruitless results, here's my attempt at my goal:

```
private static String fileDialog(Frame frame, String rootDir) {
    FileDialog filedialog = new FileDialog(frame, "Choose a File", FileDialog.LOAD);
    filedialog.setDirectory(rootDir);
    filedialog.setVisible(true);
    String dirName = filedialog.getDirectory();
    return dirName;
}
```

However I did discover a partial solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224714/how-can-i-make-a-java-filedialog-accept-directories-as-its-filetype-in-os-x), using:

```
System.setProperty(apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories, “true”)
```

But, I want it to be OS portable, which this last line does not allow.

Comment: *"It only uses AWT framework, no Swing"*  Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.