# Java file.getPath() returns language modified path

Tags: java

I need to use

```
fileChooser.getSelectedFile()
```

method however it always returns language modified path because some directories are translated in osX. For example folder "/Downloads" is translated to my system language "/Stiahnuté" but real path is "/Downloads"

return:

```
/Users/John/Stiahnuté
```

expectation

```
/Users/John/Downloads
```

If I select some sub-directory then fileChooser.getSelectedFile() returns right path again. It looks that always only last directory in path is translated

```
/Users/John/Downloads/subDirectory
```

Code:

```
saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(new FolderFilter());
                fileChooser
                        .setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    System.out.println("save path: "
                            + selectedFile.getPath());
                    doSomething(selectedFile);
                }
            }
       });
```

**UPDATE:**

I made little workaround but it is not perfect solution. However it works for me.

```
JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(
                        "Directories", "dir");
                fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
                if (fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                    File newDir = new File(selectedFile.getPath());
                    if (!newDir.exists()) {
                        newDir.mkdir();
                    }
                    doSomething();
                }
```

Comment: I would try `fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getCanonicalFile()`.  If that doesn't work, try using the more modern Path class: `fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toPath().toRealPath().toFile()`

Comment: unfortunately java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /Users/John/Stiahnuté

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the problem on Mac OS X 10.11.4 with Java 1.8.0_66. For me this looks like a bug (or at least unexpected behavior) in the implementation of `JFileChooser`. You may open a bug report for the issue.

With the help of an [answer explaining to use `FileDialog` to get a operating system native file chooser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10745286/1347968) and another [answer about using it to select directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1224744/1347968) I found the following workaround:

```
final Frame parent = …; // can be null

System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
final FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(parent);
fileDialog.setVisible(true);
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "false");

final File selectedDirectory = new File(fileDialog.getDirectory(), fileDialog.getFile());
System.out.println(selectedDirectory);
System.out.println(selectedDirectory.exists());
```

Note that using `"apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories"` is, of course, platform specific and will not work on other operating systems.