# swing file selection on a Mac OSX

Tags: macos, swing, jfilechooser

I am using JFileChooser. On a Macintosh I get this crappy crippled dialog box. I'm used to seeing the Spotlight search box that helps me find which directory something is in; how can I enable this behavior with JFileChooser?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JFileChooser for directories on the Mac: how to make it not suck?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356273/jfilechooser-for-directories-on-the-mac-how-to-make-it-not-suck)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this of some help?

[JFileChooser on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/937533/jfilechooser-on-os-x)

[How can I use a JFileChooser to select a directory?](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=121014)

[JFileChooser for directories on the Mac: how to make it not suck?](http://www.developerit.com/2010/05/12/jfilechooser-for-directories-on-the-mac-how-to-make-it-not-suck)

Comment: thanks -- the last link you posted is really on this site, the other site just duplicates content from to Stackoverflow. I wonder why I couldn't find those posts when I searched...