# Better JFileChooser alternatives for OS X, Linux?

Tags: java, linux, macos, user-interface, jfilechooser

JFileChooser, at least under OS X, produces a very half-baked open dialog that doesn't support things like typing in the start of a file name to select it or disclosure triangles.

Does anyone know of a 3rd-party alternative that has a more fully-featured behaviour? Ideally, I'd like one for each major platform. I'm aware of [XFileDialog](http://code.google.com/p/xfiledialog/) for windows, but what about Mac and Linux/Unix?

In comparison:

[image: Java's file chooser]

[image: OS X's file chooser]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/937533/86515

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the [Quaqua Look & Feel](http://www.randelshofer.ch/quaqua/), which upgrades JFileChooser a bit - it's still not perfect, but it's arguably better.

Answer (score 3):

Does `java.awt.FileDialog` do what you want, you may need to specify

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true");
```

if you want to get a directory though

Comment: Oh, it does what I want so very nearly, but it doesn't seem to support multiple selection!

Comment: Sorry, you are out of luck for multiple selection, not that it helps you now java 1.7 adds setMultipleMode to FileDialog :-(  Of course that code is open sourced in open jdk, maybe you could repackage it and bundle it with your app as long as your license is compatible (and assuming it has been updated for MAC OS, probably not).